# how to find out the exact name of error thrown in mysql node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am building a server with node.js (express) and mysql felix.

my problem is that sometime i have a query that will return a duplicate error.

I have tried everything on mind to try and catch this error without luck, the program crashes.

This is my code:

```
 this.addReservation = function(req, res, next) {
      var json = JSON.parse(req.body['reservation']);
      var post = {user1: json.player1, user2: json.player2, courtId: json.id, hour: json.hour, date: json.date};
      var giveback = {u1_first: req.user.firstName, u1_last: req.user.lastName, user1: json.player1, user2: json.player2};

      connection.query('insert into ordering set ?', post, function(err, result){
          if (err){ 
                throw err;
                return res.send(500);
            }
            else 
                return res.json({res: giveback})
                //return res.send(200);            
      });   
  };
```

now i have tried wrapping this query with try and catch. didn't help.

i tried to enter this row:

`connection.on('error', function() {console.log();});` didn't help neither.

i tried putting this line in other places still not helping.

the error that is thrown in my console is: `Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY`.

what am i doing wrong? should i use "on" on something different than 'error'?

that only thing that helped me is:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    // handle the error safely
    console.log(err);
});
```

but this is very bad as i do know the error that is caused and i wish to deal with it so this is a very bad solution for me.

please help me thanks. i am using mysql felix library.

Comment: Check https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#error-handling
connection.query('USE name_of_db_that_does_not_exist', function(err, rows) {
  console.log(err.code); // 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR'
});

Comment: i have read this but i still don't understand why my program crahses

Answer (score 1):

```
this.addReservation = function(req, res, next) {
  var json = JSON.parse(req.body['reservation']);
  var post = {user1: json.player1, user2: json.player2, courtId: json.id, hour: json.hour, date: json.date};
  var giveback = {u1_first: req.user.firstName, u1_last: req.user.lastName, user1: json.player1, user2: json.player2};

  connection.query('insert into ordering set ?', post, function(err, result){
      if (err){ 

            console.log('exact name of error thrown '+err);
            return res.send(500);
        }
        else 
            return res.json({res: giveback})
            //return res.send(200);            
  });   
};
```